# Migrating database from MySQL to SQL Server, Entity Framework still tries to use MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, entity-framework

Until recently, I used a MySQL database with Entity Framework. I have migrated this database to SQL Server.

For some reason however, Entity Framework still tries to use the MySQL provider for EF:

> MetadataException: Schema specified is not valid.
>   Errors: (0,0) : error 0175: The ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient' is either not registered in the machine or application config file, or could not be loaded. See the inner exception for details.

What I've tried so far:

- I have removed every dependency and reference to MySQL and it's provider, including any NuGet packages
- I've completely removed and re-installed Entity Framework
- Obviously, I changed my connection string
- I've even cleared all my `app.config` files (it's a WPF application) and reinstalled EF to start with a clean configuration

If I search my entire solution for MySQL, no results can be found. Still, this error occurs.

What could still cause this error?

My `app.config` (in case it matters):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" 
                 requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="sqlservercon" 
             connectionString="Data Source=<url>;Initial Catalog=<dbname>;User Id=<user>;Password=<pw>;" 
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory 
              type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
            <parameters>
                <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
            </parameters>
        </defaultConnectionFactory>
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
                      type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Context:

```
public class CustomContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }
    ...

    public CustomContext()
        : base("name=sqlservercon")
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using edmx?

Comment: Nope, I'm not..

Comment: Strange. Stack trace? Inner exception?

Comment: What is the overall project structure? The app.config in question that you pasted, is that from the main WPF executable or a domain DLL which houses the Entities/Context? Check your output directory (i.e. /bin/debug) for the .exe.config file for the application and open in VS/Notepad. Verify the connection strings here. You want to ensure that you are checking the WPF application's app.config file (not a DLL's app.config) and whether those changes are making it through to the .exe.config file or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, no extra useful info in the stack trace or inner exception. The .exe.config file is fully correct. Any app.config in the solution is properly configured...